# How do I set up a software RAID 1 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS mounted as `/data` on the same level as `/home`?

Tags: 20.04, mount, raid

How do I set up a software RAID 1 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS mounted as `/data` on the same level as `/home` (i.e. "aside" `/home`) using 2 drives with the system installed on a third drive drive?

I followed the [Software-RAID](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Software-RAID/) (in German) step by step, but it didn't work. The RAID "configured" therewith only shows up in the file manager under *Other places* → *This computer* in `/home` aside of `/[user name]` having the same capacity as `/home` on the system drive.

Note that the mounting point suggested in the guide was altered from `/media/daten` to `/home/data` for this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please see the site help on [What type of questions to avoid asking in this site](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Hello, and welcome. You should probably edit your question to remove the rants, and focus solely on the core issue. In that way, people will be more likely to help out.

Comment: +1 because downvoting without comment why is unfair imho. However I agree with @Arthur Meinild that providing a summary block with the questions would be helpful.

Comment: `The "RAID" called "data" didn't show the capacity of the RAID drives (4TB), but only the capacity of the /home partition` indicates that your RAID is not mounted at "data", so "data" is a simple empty folder in your home directory.

Comment: Question boild down to core. I'm really curious about the comments to follow.  I've learnt from the stackoverflow site already quite some time ago that it never fits. We'll see.

Comment: whow, quite a compression. Impressive. You lost your intention a bit so now its harder to understand what you mean. To make it more clear you might include the output of "lsblk" and "sudo fdisk -l" formatted as code. It helps to understand what your system is. Based on that you could describe what you have using the items from the lsblk command, e.g. "/dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1 should form a RAID1 to be mounted in /mnt/data".  The linked page is too general to know what you exactly did. Generally it helps to copy each line you type and any error ouput, so you can list that in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have three disks `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`. `/dev/sda` should be the system disk, `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` should form the RAID1 mirror for data.

From your question I understand that you have already done the first step, that is, installed the system (with root, swap, `/home` etc.) partitions on `/dev/sda`.

If the solution to create RAID using `mdadm` failed for you, I suggest using LVM (Logical Volume Manager). Basically you can follow [this guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Raid1_with_LVM_from_scratch) - it is meant for Gentoo, but should work on any Linux distribution as long as you remember to run the commands as root :) Both LVM and `parted` should be already installed in Ubuntu by default, so you should disregard the installation part.

The important steps are:

1. Create "Linux LVM" type partition on both `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` that takes up the whole disk space.
2. Create LVM **physical volumes** on both partitions.
3. Create LVM **volume group** consisting of those two physical volumes.
4. Create LVM **logical volume** of type RAID1 within this volume group.

You can find the required commands in the guide I linked.

After you do this, you should end up with a device named similar to `/dev/raid0vg0/raid0lv0`, which will represent your RAID1 volume (the exact name depends on the names you give to your volume group and logical volumes when creating them, I'm using the example name from the guide).

5. Create a filesystem on the above device ("format" in Windows terms) using `mkfs` command.
6. Create an empty `/data` directory in the root of your filesystem (or `/home/data` if you prefer).
7. Mount the created filesystem on that directory using  `mount` command. This one is not shown in the guide - it will be simply `mount /dev/raid0vg0/raid0lv0 /data` (or `mount /dev/mapper/raid0vg0-raid0lv0 /data` - these are synonymous)
8. Add an entry to `/etc/fstab` file so that the volume is mounted automatically when the system boots. It is also described in the guide how to do that.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice - I've copied your text to a local doc and will try, as soon as I've got the time to carry on with my attempts for the described system. :)